# Why landscape move double-sided page number up in LaTeX?

Tags: landscape, lscape

I need a longtable in my appendix so I used the package `lscape` or `pdflscape`, but `landscape` environment seems to move up the page number of the page just before it. See code below.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch1}
    this is ch1

\begin{landscape}
\chapter{ch2 is a long table}
    there is a long table
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chapter heading code isn't expecting to be landscaped and gets a little confused. The normal usage is

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch1}
    this is ch1

\chapter{ch2 is a long table}

\begin{landscape}

    there is a long table
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively this also works it ships out the blank page to get to an odd page before the landscape starts.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch1}
    this is ch1

\cleardoublepage
\begin{landscape}
\chapter{ch2 is a long table}
    there is a long table
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this actually cause **there is a long table** to fall into the next page, while the title of ch2 **ch2 is a long talbe** to be almost empty. Would it be possible that the title stays with the table?

Comment: @wlnirvana see update